# LibreOffice on Lubuntu focal: Incomplete pdf when exporting to pdf

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, pdf

I installed Lubuntu focal with the standard libre office. When I create a pdf (all 3 ways) I do not get the text. However I get the empty tables. I tried the same with Ubuntu and there it works. Any suggestions of what I can do?

Comment: Please specify Lubuntu and LibreOffice versions in your original post. And if they do not contain confidential information you can share your problematic documents (Write version and the broken PDF version) or a simplified version of them.

Comment: Have you tried an updated version from the Libreoffice website?

Comment: Have you installed latest patches ? Run "Software Updater". or in terminal run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Same problem here; not even exporting a "hello world" Writer document works as expected. Lubuntu 20.04, LibreOffice 6.4.3.2, all available updates (`apt update;apt upgrade`) installed.

Comment: Installing Libreoffice 6.4.3.2 from the LibreOffice website did not help; installing LibreOffice 6.3.6.2 from the LibreOffice website did not help either. Must be something in Lubuntu I guess :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove/purge libreoffice-style-breeze and libreoffice-qt5.
Doing that solves the problem for me.
(Lubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Why? Questions starting with "Try to ..." without further explanation don't look reliable,

Comment: Tried it, did not help on my machine.

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well; thank you! What I had to do, however was to restart LibreOffice.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (see comments below the question) and tried some things that did not work, i.e. purging the Ubuntu build of LibreOffice and downloading and installing LibreOffice (versions 6.4.3.2 and 6.3.6.2) from the LibreOffice website.

Since this did not help with the PDF export problem, I purged those versions too and reinstalled the "libreoffice" meta package from the Muon Package manager again. After that, suddenly the problem was fixed, exporting PDF documents now works.

BTW, I found a notice in the Lubuntu 20.04 [release documentation](https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/):

> LibreOffice Exporting Documents as a PDF There is a bug where certain
>   fonts do not render in exported PDF documents. As a workaround,
>   LibreOffice applications can be launched from the commandline with the
>   following environment variable SAL_VCL_QT5_USE_CAIRO=true. For
>   example, to launch writer issue `SAL_VCL_QT5_USE_CAIRO=true libreoffice --writer`.

Since reinstalling LibreOffice fixed the problem for me, I cannot test this workaround anymore.

Related questions/answers on other sites: [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/242188/cannot-print-anything-exporting-to-pdf-produces-blank-pdf-lubuntu-2004/)
[discourse.lubuntu.me](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/libreoffice-export-to-pdf-has-no-text/1042)

Comment: This worked for me. Same issue in latest versions of LO and Lubuntu ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem including not working printing. I unistalled "libreoffice-qt5", after that exporting and printing works. (Lubuntu 20.04, last updates).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on Lubuntu 20.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Following helped me as it is a easy way to fix it permanently.

1. Purge out LibreOffice
   Command: sudo apt-get purge libreoffice
2. Install LibreOffice from SNAP
   Command: sudo snap install libreoffice

Now everything works fine. If any issues regarding opening files on mounted drives, then you have go to Discover - > Installed app -> Libreoffice -> Permissions -> access to mounted devices